# Error when trying to translate Knowledge Articles in a test class

Tags: apex, unit-test, translation, lightning-knowledge, apextestrunresult

I have a test class in which I'm trying to translate Knowledge Articles into Spanish. Default language is English. If you were to do this from Salesforce UI, you have to publish each version individually. Specifically,

- Create Knowledge Article (In English)
- Associate Data Category
- Publish in English
- Submit for Translation
- Publish in Spanish

I have learned (from various threads) that the user trying to follow above steps should have

- "Manage Article" permission
- "Create, Read and Edit" on Knowledge
- A Role assigned

In my test class, I'm making sure I have all of above covered. However, when trying to follow the same steps, I'm getting an error on the last step (Publish in Spanish). The error I'm getting goes like - *"System.HandledException: You can't perform this action. Be sure the action is valid for the current state of the article, and that you have permission to perform it"*

Related code excerpt :

```
System.runAs(user) {
            
            for (Knowledge__kav ka : [SELECT Id, KnowledgeArticleId FROM Knowledge__kav]) {
                
                //Publish articles in English
                KbManagement.PublishingService.publishArticle(ka.KnowledgeArticleId, true); // en_US
                system.debug('## Published Id : ' + ka.Id);
                system.debug('## Published Article Id : ' + ka.KnowledgeArticleId);

                // submitForTranslation returns article ID
                String draftId = KbManagement.PublishingService.submitForTranslation(ka.KnowledgeArticleId, 'es', null, null);
                
                System.debug('## Draft ID + ' + draftId); // different from published Id
                
                // completeTranslation puts article in a publish ready state, takes articleVersionId
                KbManagement.PublishingService.completeTranslation(draftId);
                                    
                System.debug('## Translation complete');
                KbManagement.PublishingService.publishArticle(ka.KnowledgeArticleId, true); // Getting Error at this step.
                System.debug('## Published in Spanish');
            }
         }
```

I know the fact that I'm using the same KnowledgeArticleId when publishing for the second time and which may be the the cause for the issue, however, 1) the publishArticle method only accept articleId (doesn't accept articleVersionId) of which there is only one for each article but 2) You also click on publish twice on the UI for each version. Furthermore, If I submit for translation before publishing and publish only once, the Spanish version remain unpublished and that part of the code remains uncovered.

I really don't know what more to look for. Any help is much appreciated!